# unknown users when running top command

Tags: permissions, top

When I run *top* command there is 1 users listed but then other users are listed in running proecesses they are
message+, kernoops, and syslog,

I am trying to work out if my system is compromised but am a newbie and not sure what is normal for top output

when I ran *lsof -p* it showed that the permission was denied for the processes they were running which also makes me wonder if i should be concerned

there are a lot of root processes running with PIDs other than 0 is this normal too?
thanks

Comment: What does the command `pinky` tell you? (Or you could install 'finger') if you want more options.

Comment: Oh, and it's quite normal that there are "system" users that own processes. I currently have processes from the following users: artur, root, systemd, messagebu, syslog, daemon, unbound. And I'm only logged in with myself.

Comment: pinky - i am the only user. thats great, so they are system users. I will know what to look out for another time, thanks